# bootstrap grid system not formatting correctly without commenting out a class='col-md-6'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have user who have not created a profile to be directed to a page that instructs them to do so. 
If user has not created a profile, I would like the bootstrap well to go across the page. I can only get it to work by commenting out line 7 (or the first: div class="col-md-6") , which messes up the interface if user has created a profile.

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Jr. Dev Mentoring</h1>
  <h3>Harnessing the Power of Mentorship <br>To Build A Community of Work Ready Jr. Devs.</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <h2 class="text-center">Your Profile</h2>
        <% if current_user.profile %>
          <%= link_to "Edit your profile", "#", class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
          <%= link_to "View your profile", user_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <% if current_user.plan.name == "mentor" %>
          <%= render partial: "pages/mentor" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render partial: "pages/mentee" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
        <% else %>
           <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
                <p class='text-center'>Create your profile so that you can share your information with the Jr. Dev Mentoring community.</p>
                <%= link_to "Create your profile", new_user_profile_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block'%>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <h2 class="text-center">Mentee</h2>
        <h4 class="text-center">Sign up for free to gain access to our community of mentors.</h4>
        <br/>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path(plan: @mentee_plan.id), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <h2 class="text-center">Mentor</h2>
        <h4 class="text-center">Sign up for free to lend your expertise and support!</h4><br>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path(plan: @mentor_plan.id), class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

[image: This is how I want it to look but it only works if I comment out line which messes up other interface]

[image: How it looks if I don't comment out line]

[image: This is the other interface that it messes up if I comment out line]

Comment: if you like the way it looks for users with no profile when you comment out line 7, use a conditional to put the line on the page.

Comment: I thought about that, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: so, you want that? I can drop some codes.

Comment: that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: You had a slight mis-arrangement around line 7, :).

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Welcome to Jr. Dev Mentoring</h1>
  <h3>Harnessing the Power of Mentorship <br>To Build A Community of Work Ready Jr. Devs.</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if current_user.profile %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
          <h2 class="text-center">Your Profile</h2>
          <%= link_to "Edit your profile", "#", class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
          <%= link_to "View your profile", user_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <% if current_user.plan.name == "mentor" %>
          <%= render partial: "pages/mentor" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render partial: "pages/mentee" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
            <p class='text-center'>Create your profile so that you can share your information with the Jr. Dev Mentoring community.</p>
            <%= link_to "Create your profile", new_user_profile_path(current_user), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block'%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <h2 class="text-center">Mentee</h2>
        <h4 class="text-center">Sign up for free to gain access to our community of mentors.</h4>
        <br/>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path(plan: @mentee_plan.id), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well">
        <h2 class="text-center">Mentor</h2>
        <h4 class="text-center">Sign up for free to lend your expertise and support!</h4><br>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path(plan: @mentor_plan.id), class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you...let me check my mis-arrangement

Comment: So all that needed to be done was that one line needed to be moved? Man. Well, at least I'd gotten that far :-)